# Set typeface with custom font for alert dialog items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm creating an alert dialog this way:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
alertDialog.setCustomTitle(null);
alertDialog.setItems(getAllListNames(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
      //Doing something awesome...
  }
});
```

I know it creates a list view with my items, I want to set a typeface with a custom font for them and also set a max number of characters for each list item, how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a custom theme. Here is the official guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html :)

Something like this (in the `style.xml` file):

```
<style name="CustomFontTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

Then when you create the dialog you can do this:

```
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(view.getContext(), R.style.CustomFontTheme)
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Where `R.style.CustomFontTheme` is the id for the them you have created.

---

**Update:**

Ok, to add your custom typeface you can follow this gist:
https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076

The key is to override the a given font face when the application starts like this:

```
TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "AWESOME-FONT", "fonts/Awesome-Font.ttf");
```

the gist has the implementation for that method.

So the theme styles should look like this now:

```
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">awesome-font</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">awesome-font</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my font is not a roboto font, it's loaded programatically, so I guess it won't work..

Comment: I've updated my question with a gist that show how to load a new typeface with some reflection magic

Comment: @pablisco, is this code overrides the entire application's font or just the `AlertDialog` font?

Comment: `TypefaceUtil` Should add the font to the application context. Then you can apply it where needed. You can add it to the global theme for all textView instances with `textViewStyle`. If you want it only on the dialog then have a separate theme and inflate the dialog with that theme.