# Cannot resolve method setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a custom font family for my `AlertDialog` but `Android` states the following:

```
Cannot resolve method setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)
```

Below is my code:

```
TextView settingsTitle =  new TextView(this);
        settingsTitle.setText("Settings");
        settingsTitle.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        settingsTitle.setTextSize(20);
        settingsTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

        AlertDialog settingsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCustomTitle(settingsTitle)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();

        Typeface standardFont = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
        settingsDialog.setTypeface(standardFont);
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303811/set-typeface-with-custom-font-for-alert-dialog-items

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` does not have a method named `setTypeface()`. You cannot call a method that doesn't exist.